How to implement shedlock in springboot project that is using custom base repository?
I see many examples online that integrates shedlock in a springboot project that uses MongoRepository. However, i am using my own custom base repository that utilises mongodb by adding a @Qualifier annotation to a mongodb database name.
I do not have the spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb dependency.
How do i configure shedlock?
